# Wireless interface wifi0 not present

Tags: wireless

I have Lenovo Z575 and problems with Wifi connection. After a short battle with drivers, and eventually installing *ndiswrapper* and windows drivers, *wifi0* interface does not show up in the *ifconfig*...

`ifconfig -a` gives only `lo` and `eth0`.

Although, wireless hardware *is* presend; `lspci` gives `02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe`

Simple `ifup wifi0`
gives `Ignoring unknown interface wifi0=wifi0.`

Any idea how to fix wifi?

**Edit**

`rfkill unblock all` does not help

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ndiswrapper` and all settings related to that.

Download linux driver from the [official site](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501) for your product (most likely [RT3090PciE](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5015))

Assuming you saved it to `Downloads` directory, follow the commands to compile it

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential`

`cd Downloads`

`tar -xaf <DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME>.tar.bz2`

`cd <DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME>`

`WPA1=HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT`

`WPA2=HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT`

`sed -i -e "s/$WPA1=n/$WPA1=y/g" -e "s/$WPA2=n/$WPA2=y/g" os/linux/config.mk`

`sudo make && sudo make install && sudo make clean`

Comment: Thanks. I applied this patch (http://www.infty.nl/wordpress/2011/09/patches-for-the-ralink-rt3090-linux-driver/) to compile it, did `make` and `make install` but still I do not see the interface (after restart)